# Use arrays from tableView if statement in another viewcontrollers

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement, tableview

I need to create two "help" arrays according to if results in table view.
My main problem is: How can I use this arrays in another view controller?

etc.: Beacause when I want to use one array in another controller with TableViewController().helpArrayOne it is empty/or not exist in tableViewController, but after print in tableViewController I get values, thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

 let listOfStudents = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.stringValue}

        for key in listOfStudents{

            // Compare data

           if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {

           cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"false_icon")

           var helpArrayOne:[String] = []

           helpArrayOne.append(all[indexPath.row].id)

           var helpArrayTwo:[String] = []

           helpArrayTwo.append(all[indexPath.row].stringValue)

           break

        } else {

            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"true_icon")

                }
        }
        print(helpArrayOne,helpArrayTwo)
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember scope; declare the arrays as instance variables that are optionals. Then you will be able to pass them into another view controller from anywhere else in the scope of the current view controller.

Just make sure that they are being passed after the value has been assigned to them.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { [weak self] in

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

 let listOfStudents = allUrl.reduce(into: [String:String]()){$0[$1.id] =  $1.stringValue}

        for key in listOfStudents{

            // Compare data

           if  cell.textLabel?.text == key.key {

           cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"false_icon")



           self?.helpArrayOne.append(all[indexPath.row].id)



           self?.helpArrayTwo.append(all[indexPath.row].stringValue)

           break

        } else {

            cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"true_icon")

                }
        }
        print(helpArrayOne,helpArrayTwo)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: sry,I try to compile and it was without error, but when I tab on this view controller I get an error on this lines:   self?.helpArrayOne.append(all[indexPath.row].id)

Comment: Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type ViewController.Replace ? with ". Value of type ViewController has no member helpArrayOne

Comment: any suggestions?